# How do I interact with the four Eloquent models correctly?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

The project consists of four related tables:

1. orders (id, status, client_email, partner_id)
2. order_products (id, order_id, product_id, quantity, price)
3. partners (id, email, name)
4. prods (id, name, price, vendor_id)

creating 4 models:

```
    <?php
    //App\Order.php
    namespace App;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Order extends Model
    {
        protected $fillable = [
      'id',  'status', 'client_email', 'partner_id',
    ];

public function partner()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Partner');
  }

public function order_product()
  {
//belongsToMany - server error
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Prod', 'order_products');
  }

public function prod()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Prod');
  }

    }
```

---

```
<?php
//App\Partner.php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Partner extends Model
{
   protected $fillable = ['id', 'email', 'name'];

public function order()
  {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Order');
  }

}
```

---

```
    <?php
    //App\Order_product.php
    namespace App;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Order_product extends Model
    {
        protected $fillable = ['order_id', 'product_id', 'quantity', 'price'];

 public function order()
  {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Order');
  }

    }
```

---

```
    <?php
    //App\Prod.php
    namespace App;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Prod extends Model
    {
        protected $fillable = ['order_id', 'product_id', 'quantity', 'price'];

    public function order()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order', 'order_products');
  }

    }
```

creating Order Resources:

```
<?php
//App\Http\Resources\Order.php
namespace App\Http\Resources;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class Order extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id'           => $this->id,
        'status'       => $this->status,
        'client_email' => $this->client_email,
        'partner_id'   => $this->partner_id,
        'partner_name' => $this->partner->name,

        //return server error
        'product_id'   => Prod::collection($this->order_product), 
        'name'         => $this->prod->name,

    ];

}

}
```

creating Prod Resource:

```
<?php
//App/Http/Resources\Prode.php
namespace App\Http\Resources;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class Prod extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id'      => $this->id,
            'name'    => $this->name,
            'price'   => $this->price,
        ];
    }
}
```

And return from Order Controller:

```
<?php
//App\Http\Controllers\Api\OrderController.php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Order;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Resources\Order as OrderResource;

class OrderController extends Controller
{
public function index()
  {
    $orders = Order::with(['partner', 'order_product', 'prod'])->get();
    return OrderResource::collection($orders);
   }
}
```

How do I get the product name in the order?

Answer (score 1):

`Order_product` seems like a name for a pivot table. This isn't necessary in laravel because the frameworks assumes the table structure by default. The recommended approach is creating the following models:

- Order

```php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',  'status', 'client_email', 'partner_id',
    ];

    public function partner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Partner');
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'order_products');
    }

    public function prod()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Prod');
    }
}
```

- Product (Prod)

```php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'prod';
    protected $fillable = ['order_id', 'product_id', 'quantity', 'price'];

    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order', 'order_products');
    }
}
```

and with the following resources:

**OrderResource**

```
<?php
//App\Http\Resources\Order.php
namespace App\Http\Resources;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class OrderResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id'           => $this->id,
            'status'       => $this->status,
            'partner_id'   => $this->partner_id,
            'partner_name' => $this->partner->name,
           'products'    =>  ProductResource::collection($this->products), 
           'name'          => $this->prod->name,
        ];

    }
}
```

**ProductResource**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Resources;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class ProductResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id'           => $this->id,
            'name'       => $this->name,
            'price'   => $this->price,
        ];

    }
}
```

more details over [many to many relations](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) can be found in the docs.

Comment: But the line: `'product_id'    => $this->order_product->product_id,` is not even possible because one order has multiple products?

Comment: Yes, there may be more than one product in the order. I already have the `products` table and it is used for other purposes. `Product Resource` is also available. And I don't understand how to use the `prods` table.  I tweaked my post based on your comments. Please take a look.

Comment: Why is there a product and prod table for storing products? Can you merge them into one? This makes it possible for laravel to infer relations